# Processes locking on multicore machine

Tags: java, multicore

I recently started running my java program on my new multicore machine. I am suddenly seeing a problem which never occurred on my old single core Pentium. I suspect that the issue has to do with some sort of contention between my program and the various browsers I am running at the same time. When the processes get into this state, no amount of killing of processes seems to help (there's always some residual firefox or chrome process), so I end up restarting the machine. My program does a lot of opening and reading of URLs essentially using the following lines:

```
URL url = new URL( urlString );

URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

........

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null ) {...}
```

Every so often the URL my program tries to hit does not exist. In these cases, the call to create the BufferedReader eventually times out. I am going to modify the program to use a shorter time out, but I suspect that this in itself is not going to fix the problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that your Java application interacts with your browsers? Are you writing a Applet or a Servlet?

Comment: What you say doesn't make much sense. After all, JVM runs in a separate process, different from the browsers.

Comment: Are both (old & new) connected to the same network? Because "locking" can be caused by a stalling network connection as the read() method of InputStream blocks until data is available.

Comment: Do you close the input stream as soon as you're done reading from it?

Comment: My program is an independent process (regular java app running in its own JVM). I don't have definitive proof of contention between the app and browsers - it's just a suspicion for now - either way I definitely don't remember seeing the problem on the single core pentium...

Comment: New and old machines are running on my home network, using the same connection into the internet. So is it possible that a stalling network connection on one process locks the connection for other processes on the same machine ?

Comment: Looking at the code anew, I see that I actually do not close the stream after reading from it (feeling embarrassed - let me fix that pronto) - can that be the cause of the problem, though ? Then why would it be a problem only on the multi-core box ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the system change is a red herring. When you working with raw URL connection on the jdk there might be an issue. There is no in built retry mechanism and you will have to write all the code yourself. Try the HTTP client library from Apache. That should more or less solve any problem you face with URLConnection - http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a good suggestion. I guess it will take some substantial rewrite but it shouldn't be too bad.